# Styling of HTML5 progress bars

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I am making a game including HTML5 progress bars, however I have more than one and would like the colours to be different. I currently have styling that sets all the progress bars to one colour but I am not sure how to make different bars different colours.
Here is my current CSS:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
background-color: gray;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
background-color: lime;
}
```

(I am using safari)

Comment: You might use CSS classes or IDs to differentiate progress bars and set different styles for each of them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to define the class for WebKit in that class and am not sure how

Comment: the progress element itself may have class "class1" or "class2" or "class3" ... simply use `progress.class1::--webkit-porgess-bar {` etc or, an ancestor element of the progress bar may have different classes ... so `.class1 progress::--webkit-porgess-bar {` etc

Comment: If you could show us an example of your HTML that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different classes for the different progress bars.

```css
progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.progress1::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: gray;
}

.progress1::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: lime;
}

.progress2::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<progress class="progress1" value="32" max="100"> 32% </progress>
<progress class="progress2" value="32" max="100"> 32% </progress>
```